# django Sessions are not maintaing in an iframe

Tags: django, iframe, django-sessions

I am creating a conversational chatbot using django . And To maintain the flow of the chat in  chatbot , i am using django sessions . But when i use the link of the chatbot in an iframe , it doesn't store any of the session and flow breaks down. I want a function that will help to maintain the sessions even in the iframe.

For for Iframe

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<embed style=" width: 384px; height: 525px; margin-right: 0px !important; bottom: 0px; float: right; position: absolute; bottom: 30px; width: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" src="http://*********.com/********/*******.html">


</body>
</html>
```

Code For maintaining sessions

```
@staticmethod
    def extract_data(request, input_data):
        from chat import validations
        if 'city' not in request.session:
            response_data = {'extra': {}, 'data': {}}
            response_data['extra']['statement'] = 'Select Car Model which you like to rent?'
            response_data['extra']['type'] = 'carmodel'
            response_data['data'] = Cars.city_check(request,response_data, input_data)

        elif 'veh_name' not in request.session:

            response_data = Cars.veh_name_check(request, input_data)

        elif 'days' not in request.session:
            response_data = validations.days_check(request, input_data)

        elif 'phone' not in request.session:
            response_data = validations.phone_check(request, input_data)

        elif 'email' not in request.session:

            response_data = validations.mail_check(request, input_data)

        elif 'name' not in request.session:
            response_data = validations.name_check(request, input_data, 'Car')

        return response_data
```

Comment: Hi Is there anyone who has resolved this issues?

Comment: I think this is because of the restrictions on 3rd party cookies?

Comment: Can you show the code where you have set these session variables. Thanks

Comment: it has something to do with cross-domain cookies. Enable your browser's third party cookie and try your web application again

Answer (score 5):

This has little to do with django. Browsers are currently paranoid about giving frames/embeds access to cookies, even when they are the source of the cookie. In addition, many users block third-party cookies (which usually includes frame cookies), or all cookies. You could embed a session id in the frame source, as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25412908/11529348), with the session id generated (either completely random or from cookie) by django template or client-side javascript *on the page that contains the frame* which might have access to the cookie.

You may also want to look into dropping the embed/frame entirely in favor of a django include block, which inserts the chat content window into the containing page as a div or similar, therefor giving greater access to cookies or other session variables. In this case I'd separate the javascript from the html and put the js script tag in the head.

As a last-ditch shot, you could replace the dependency on cookies with a combination of the client's public ip and user-agent, and maybe the containing-pages URI (in the case of a template).

**Edit** With regard to security: (after a comment by @EthanKeller)

Browsers try to protect frames from main content and vice versa. It all depends on rather either contains any sensitive info. If so, then I suggest separating them by putting the frame in it's own window/tab, potentially via popup call. In the case of a chatbot, however, I doubt there is anything all that sensitive. Dealer's choice.

Comment: Ooof - all of those options expose other security holes. I knew about 3rd party cookie prevention (see my earlier comment.) Thanks for the suggestion - I think the best answer here is 'don't do it!'

Comment: @EthanKeller I agree that this is a potential security issue. Frames and the like always are. See edit for alternative.

Answer (score 5):

To allow cookies from an iframe, you have to set your cookie using `SameSite=None` and `Secure` options.

```
Set-Cookie: session=your_session; SameSite=None; Secure
```

Source: https://medium.com/trabe/cookies-and-iframes-f7cca58b3b9e

To do this with Django, you'll have to update the following settings:

- [`SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite)
- [`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-cookie-secure)

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'  # As a string
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Unfortunately, `'None'` value for `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE` is only available since Django 3.1 and there is [no plan to backport it in 3.0 and 2.2](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31933#comment:1).

Also note that your website has to be served over HTTPS.