# Not able to maintain login in iframe for django

Tags: python, django, iframe

I am trying to maintain the login session in an iframe for a Django website.

When the iframe is embedded in the same domain (`example.com`) the login session is maintained.

But when the iframe is embedded in another domain (`another.com`) the login of `example.com` is not there, even though the `src` of the iframe is set to `example.com`.

django version `Django==2.1.5`

Comment: The answer to this question might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627038/django-sessions-are-not-maintaing-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your session cookie using `SameSite=None` and `Secure` options.

To do this with django, update [`SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite) and [`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-cookie-secure) in your settings:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'  # As a string
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Another requirement is that your website is served via HTTPS.

Comment: when I try this I get `samesite must be "lax" or "strict".`

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Seems like `"None"` was introduced in 3.1.

Comment: Yes, I saw that I have `Django==2.1.5` so the above solution doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think any other solution would work. Unless handling sessions/cookies yourself but that would imply rewriting a lot of code Django provides for you. To me, the best solution would be to upgrade to Django 3.1 (Note that 2.1 is unsupported since December 2019). Another solution would be to monkeypatch Django or fork it to apply the following patch: https://github.com/django/django/commit/b33bfc383935cd26e19a2cf71d066ac6edd1425f but these techniques are out of the scope of this question.

Comment: There is a ticket to backport these changes to Django 2.2 and Django 3.0, but it was apparently rejected. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31933